# A VB.NET application exits without exception

Tags: vb.net

My application exits sometime without any exception. I am using a loop in a separate thread to read an [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) device. I think the problem is there. But I am not sure what causes this problem. What is wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub USBListenServer()
    If (readHandle IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Not readHandle.IsInvalid) Then
        Try
            Dim dataBytes(&H40) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Int32
            Do
                If (readHandle IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
                   (Not readHandle.IsInvalid) AndAlso _
                   (Not readHandle.IsClosed) AndAlso _
                    HID_Read(hidHandle, readHandle, writeHandle, dataBytes, bytesRead) AndAlso _
                    (bytesRead > 0) Then

                    Dim myDataBytes(&H40) As Byte
                    Array.Resize(Of Byte)(myDataBytes, bytesRead - 1)
                    Array.Copy(dataBytes, 1, myDataBytes, 0, bytesRead - 1)
                    Dim _dataArrivedEvent As DataArrivedEventHandler = DataArrivedEvent
                    If _dataArrivedEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                        _dataArrivedEvent.Invoke(myDataBytes)
                    End If
                End If
            Loop While (listenServerRunning)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End If
    Application.ExitThread()
End Sub

Private Function HID_Read(ByVal hHandle As SafeFileHandle, ByVal rHandle As SafeFileHandle, _
                          ByVal wHandle As SafeFileHandle, ByRef dataBytes As Byte(), _
                          ByRef BytesRead As Int32) As Boolean

    Dim hidOverlapped As New NativeOverlapped
    Dim eventObject As IntPtr
    Dim nonManagedBuffer As IntPtr
    Dim nonManagedOverlapped As IntPtr
    Dim numberOfBytesRead As Int32
    Dim result As Int32
    Dim success As Boolean

    ' Setup the overlapped structure for the ReadFile.
    PrepareForOverlappedTransfer(hidOverlapped, eventObject)

    ' Allocate memory for the input buffer and overlapped structure.
    nonManagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dataBytes.Length)
    nonManagedOverlapped = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(hidOverlapped))
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(hidOverlapped, nonManagedOverlapped, False)

    ' ***
    ' Attemps to read an Input Report from the device.
    ' Parameters:
    ' A device handle returned by the createfile. (for Overlapped I/O, CreateFile must has been called with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.)
    ' A pointer to a buffer for storing the report.
    ' The input report length in bytes returned by HidP_GetCaps.
    ' A pointer to a variable that will hold the number of bytes read.
    ' An overlapped structure whose hEvent member is set to an event object.

    ' The overlapped called returns immediately, even if the data hasn't been received yet.

    ' To read the multiple reports with one ReadFile, increase the size of ReadBuffer and use NumberOfBytesRead to determine how many reports were returned.
    ' Use a larger buffer if the application can't keep up with reading report individually.
    ' ***
    success = ReadFile(rHandle, nonManagedBuffer, dataBytes.Length, numberOfBytesRead, nonManagedOverlapped)

    If Not (success) Then
        Select Case Marshal.GetLastWin32Error

            Case &H3E5
                ''Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for ReadFile...") '//Comment out to avoid overload writing text file
                ' Wait for at least one report or a time-out. Used with overlapped ReadFile.
                result = WaitForSingleObject(eventObject, 100)

                ' Find out if the ReadFile completed or timeout.
                Select Case result
                    Case WAIT_OBJECT_0
                        ' ReadFile has completed.
                        success = True
                        ''Debug.WriteLine("ReadFile completed successfully.") //Comment out to avoid overload writing text file

                        ' Get the number of bytes read.
                        '
                        ' Get the result of an overlapped operation.
                        ' Accepts:
                        ' A device handle returned by CreateFile.
                        ' A pointer to an overlapped structure.
                        ' A pointer to a variable to hold the number of bytes read.
                        ' False to return immediately.
                        GetOverlappedResult(rHandle, nonManagedOverlapped, numberOfBytesRead, False)

                    Case WAIT_TIMEOUT
                        ' cancel the operation on timeout
                        CancelTransfer(hHandle, rHandle, wHandle, eventObject)
                        ''Debug.WriteLine("ReadFile timeout.")    //Comment out to avoid overload writing text file
                        success = False

                    Case Else
                        ' cancels the operation on other error
                        CancelTransfer(hHandle, rHandle, wHandle, eventObject)
                        ''Debug.WriteLine("ReadFile undefined errro.")    //Comment out to avoid overload writing text file
                        success = False
                End Select
        End Select
    End If

    If success Then
        ' A report was received. Copy the received data to inputReportBuffer for the application to use.
        Marshal.Copy(nonManagedBuffer, dataBytes, 0, numberOfBytesRead)
        BytesRead = numberOfBytesRead
    End If

    If Not (nonManagedOverlapped = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nonManagedOverlapped)
    End If

    If Not (nonManagedBuffer = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nonManagedBuffer)
    End If

    Return success
End Function
```

Comment: Catching an exception and rethrowing it is utterly pointless. If an exception is unhandled, it bubbles up the stack automatically. You don't have to (and shouldn't) help it. Remove the `Try`/`Catch` block from your first function entirely.

Comment: I doing without Try/Catch, but the problem can't solve. Thanks.

Comment: If the application crashes because of an unhandled exception, there should be an entry in the Application eventlog with the exception's stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that an exception *is* being raised.  Since the exception isn't raised on the *UI* thread you won't see the normal crash dialog.  You should try logging the exception to some kind of debug output inside your catch block (console output, trace log, or windows event viewer).

Comment: I try using try catch and produce log file. But there is no log result (appear no exception) and the application also terminate whthout reason.